# Firefox Extension createing - insertCSS onclick work but how to onload?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

i try to do my first firefox extension. It´s really simple. Create toolbar button. After click insert or remove CSS (i use local storage ... after insert i save true and after removeCSS i save false)
I create button, after click everything works.

But problem is ... i want to check true/false (after load new page) from storage and if it´s true automatically insertCSS. If false don´t do anything.

How could i do this? toolbar button click works, but i want to execute script onload to check actual status and if it´s true, insertCSS.

manifest.json

```
 
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "scripts test",
  "description": "INSERT CSS to page",
  "version": "1.1,",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*.greatWorld.org/*" ],
      "js": [ "func.js" ]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "on.svg",
      "32": "on.svg"
    }
  },

  "permissions": [ "notifications", "storage", "tabs", "activeTab" ]
}
```

background.js

```
 

if (!localStorage.getItem('actstate2')) {
    populateStorage();
};




function openPage() {

        if (localStorage.getItem('actstate2') == "true") {
            browser.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "on.svg" });
            browser.tabs.insertCSS({ file: "content-style.css" });
            localStorage.setItem('actstate2', false);

        } else {
            browser.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "off.svg" });
            browser.tabs.removeCSS({ file: "content-style.css" });
            localStorage.setItem('actstate2', true);

        }
    };


function populateStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem('actstate2', false);
}


browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openPage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [browser.contentScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contentScripts) to register/unregister the automatic injection of CSS:

```js
let scriptHandle;

function toggle() {
  const newState = !(localStorage.actstate2 === 'true');
  localStorage.actstate2 = newState;
  browser.browserAction.setIcon({path: newState ? 'on.svg' : 'off.svg'});
  browser.tabs[newState ? 'insertCSS' : 'removeCSS']({file: 'content-style.css'});
  toggleAutoInjection(newState);
}

async function toggleAutoInjection(enable) {
  if (enable) {
    scriptHandle = await browser.contentScripts.register({
      css: ['content-style.css'],
      runAt: 'document_start',
      matches: browser.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts[0].matches,
    });
  } else if (scriptHandle) {
    scriptHandle.unregister();
    scriptHandle = null;
  }
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(toggle);
```

Comment: Hi, really thanks for quick response. Great script. Can i ask you once more? How can i load toggle() on page load without clicking button? At real i need to click button and enable extension script ... and it will work automatically (without clicking on every pages) on all matched pages. If i click again (actstate2 false) it will stop inserting css. At real, i need to enable / disable my extension with button...but what i read online,I can't do it directly. So i´m trying to find another way.

Comment: Call it at the end of the script: if (localStorage.actstate2 === 'true') toggleAutoInjection(true); and also set the icon browser.browserAction.setIcon({path: localStorage.actstate2 === 'true' ? 'on.svg' : 'off.svg'});

Comment: Interesting ... i added that to end of background.js. it works partially. after restart browser, toolbar button appearance works ... have last set true/false value. But even that it´s true css inject doesn´t work...just when clicking on button...

Comment: Sounds like the tabs load before the background script, in which case you'll need to process all tab explicitly via browser.tabs.query + loop + browser.tabs.insertCSS